# Let $f:R→S$ be a ring homomorphism. Let $I$ be an ideal of $R$. Can we describe the condition that ideal generated by $f(I)$ is prime ideal of $S$?

Tags: abstract-algebra, polynomials, ring-theory, ideals

Let $f:R→S$ be a ring homomorphism. Let $I$ be an ideal of $R$.  Can we describe the condition that ideal generated by $f(I)$ is prime ideal of $S$ ?

For example, I'm thinking this kind of question ;
$R＝\Bbb{R}[u,v,t]$, $f$ is determined by  $S＝\Bbb{R}[x,y]$, $f(u)＝x+y,f(v)＝xy, f(t)＝x$, and
$I=(u-a,v-b)$($a,b$ is real number). I'm seeking a condition of $(a,b)$ such that $f(I)$ is prime idela of $S$.

(If $f$ is surjective and $I$ contains $kerf$, ideal generated by $f(I)$ is $f(I)$ and $f(I)$ is prime ideal.  But in general case($f$ is not necessarily surjective) , what is sufficient and necessary conditon of $I$ ? )

Comment: Not much can be said in general, as far as I know.

Comment: What do you think about this(second paragraph) particular example ?

Comment: In that case you want $(x+y-a, xy-b)$ to be a prime ideal, which is the same thing as $ x(a-x) - b$ to be irreducible which you can figure out using the quadratic formula..

Comment: Could you tell me how did you find the ideal prime if only if $x(a-x)-b$ is irreducible ?

Answer (score 1):

In your example, $f(I)=(x+y-a,xy-b)$, so we want a condition for when the quotient
$$A:=\mathbb R[x,y]/(x+y-a,xy-b)$$
is an integral domain. If $b=0$ then $xy=0\in A$, so $A$ is not a domain. Thus, assume $b\ne0$, in which case
$$A\cong \mathbb R[x,x^{-1}]/(x+bx^{-1}-a),$$
which is a localization of $\mathbb R[x]/(x^2-ax+b)$. If $x^2-ax+b$ is irreducible, then $\mathbb R[x]/(x^2-ax+b)\cong\mathbb C$ is a domain. Otherwise, if $x^2-ax+b$ splits into two factors, then $\mathbb R[x]/(x^2-ax+b)\cong\mathbb R\times\mathbb R$ is not a domain. The last case is when $x^2-ax+b=(x-c)^2$ for some real number $c$. If $c\ne0$, the same arguments show $A$ is not a domain, and when $c=0$, we have $A=0$, which is again not a domain.

In conclusion, $f(I)\subset S$ is a prime ideal iff $x^2-ax+b$ is irreducible, i.e., iff $4a^2-b<0$.

Comment: Thank you for good approach. My book reads 'finding $kerf$ is a hint', but how can I do that ?

Comment: $f$ should be injective, since $f(u)$ and $f(v)$ are elementary symmetric polynomials (in $x$ and $y$), but $f(t)$ isn't symmetric. So, there cannot exist any nontrivial algebraic relations between $f(u)$, $f(v)$, and $f(t)$.

Comment: I don't see, $v-ut＋t^2∈kerf$,

Comment: Oh yes, my bad, you're right.